# set SVG image and img with min-width in %

Tags: html, css

Is it posible to set a SVG Image with a min-width in %? because its not working for me. The same for an Image. Both are set to fit 100% of the containing div. When i resize my browser i want the image to stop resizing when it reaches a min-width.

html

```
<div id="first">
  <img href="" alt="si"/>
</div>
```

css

```
#first{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#first img{
    width:100%;
    min-width:50%;
}
```

Comment: `%` values are relative to the parent element. In this case, the image will have a minimum width of `50%` of `#first`, which will never be satisfied because you're telling it to have a width of `100%`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%` is relative to width of parent `div`, And for outer most `div` it is relative to browser's width.

Suppose you want that image should not get smaller than 200px, use script below

```
#first img{
    width:100%;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

Here if `#first` width is greater than 200px than image scales or remains 200px min.

Answer (score 0):

`first` is a parent to your image and its width is `width:100%`. However, your image's minimum width is 50% and the percent values are relative to the parent element, so your preference is not quite possible under these circumstances.